# Rechargeable batteries with DC motor

Tags: power-supply, batteries, dc, dc-motor

I'm doing some research for a hobby project I'm working on. The project includes a DC motor (~8-10W) and an Arduino.

I've noticed that I have a choice between 6V motors and 12V motors- 12V will be more efficient but looking at many small projects/products, they all use 6V.

From this, I have a few questions:

- Why do these products use 6V? Is it because the rechargeable battery can be smaller/for cost reasons in return for a lower efficiency i.e. higher currents? I thought that rechargeable batteries comprise of cells so a 12V voltage just means putting connecting a few more cells. Just wanted to know if there is a deeper reason for why one would choose a 6V motor over a 12V if the efficiency gains are significant.
- Currently, I'm powering my Arduino circuit via USB (5V) and a small motor via a battery i.e. on a separate circuit (with common ground). I only want to use a single power source. I'm thinking of using a 6V/12V power source (depending on which motor I end up with) with some form of power regulation circuit that steps down the voltage to the 5V needed by the Arduino. Is this possible and if so what are the names for these type of circuits so I can do some further reading?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're first question is not really something I think anyone can speak to definitively, but I'd be inclined to suggest the following.

a) Once a voltage becomes common for a product type, manufacturers are incentivized to use that voltage type in order to appeal to customers who already use the part. You could, for example, make a device that uses 5V3 logic, but no one would buy it because it would work with nothing else.

b) 6V, and by extension 12V, are convenient compared to batteries, lots of which have nominal voltages of 1.5V, hence a 6V motor can run directly off 4 batteries.

As to why one would choose one motor over another, that part of the question is actually pretty deep. Yes, there's efficiency to consider, but also torque - both at the stall and other rpms - rpm, price, and weight to name a few. Why you'd choose a 6V motor over a 12V is a bit more complicated than just the voltage.

For your application, that's exactly what I'd do, you're looking for a DC-to-DC converter, and in this case, you don't need it to be isolated. I'd find a motor that suited other requirements of my project, and then get a PSU to suit.

Comment: Awesome thanks- that makes sense. For my use case, efficiency is very important, even if this means running a slightly more expensive motor. That's why I was thinking of going with the 12V. But from what I see, most manufacturers use 6V. I might start with 6V and change it out for 12V later down the line. I'm probably going to use some Li-ion cells (3.7V nominal) so will probably use a few cells in series with the dc-dc converter (on first look, a buck regulator may be what I need). Thanks again!

Comment: @testing great stuff. If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting it, or marking it as the answer.